# js variable behaves differently in two events

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables, global-variables

I am creating an order form with items. People enter number of items required in the input field. As they do, a keyUp function calculates total of each item and displays next to it. At the same time, at the bottom of the table, the final total cost and total number of items are displayed. All this is done in JS. This is then passed to next page with PHP. This is a confirmation page. Then the user clicks proceed button to submit the data to the next page where data is inserted into databases.

All This works fine.

However, at the confirmation page, there is an Edit button which on click brings back the order form. There all the previous data and total are correctly there which the user can edit and resubmit. Except for the total number of items which shows double of what was previously submitted

The code is

```
$('document').ready(function(){

        $("input").each(function() {
                    $(this).keyup(function(){

                        calculateSum();
                    });

                });
});
    calculateSum();

    function calculateSum() {

    //Calculate Total Items
            var sum = 0;
            var totcost=0;
            //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
            $("input").each(function() {

                //add only if the value is number
                if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0 && this.value.length<=3) {
                    sum += eval(parseInt(this.value));
                }
            });

    //Calculate Total Cost
            $("div.ittot").each(function() {
                var tots=0;
                var str=$(this).text();
                var thenum = str.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
                var tots = parseInt(thenum,10);

                //add only if the value is number
                if(!isNaN(tots) && tots.length!=0) {
                    totcost += tots;
                }
            });

        $("#totalcost").css("background-color", "green").html("<div style='float:left;margin-left:5px'><span style='font-weight:700'>Total Cost : </span>Rs."+ totcost + "</div><div style='float:right;margin-right:5px'><span style='font-weight:700'>Total Items : </span>" + sum + "</div><div style='clear:both'></div>");
    }
```

The totcost variable works perfectly fine.

But the sum variable doesn't get reset on each function call and compounds the total every time instead of totaling afresh each time.

What is wrong ? Both have same commands.

**Edit**

The complete order form code as requested

```
    include('conn.php');
    $itemsc="";
    $arraytable = array();

$result=$orderdb->query("SELECT * FROM rates ORDER BY item");

if ($result) {

/* Get field information for all columns */
    while ($finfo = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $arraytable[$finfo['item']] = $finfo['rate'];

        if($finfo['type']=="Male"){
            $itemsm[]=$finfo['item'];
            $itemsidm[]=$finfo['id'];
        }
        elseif($finfo['type']=="Female"){
                $itemsf[]=$finfo['item'];
                $itemsidf[]=$finfo['id'];
            }
        elseif($finfo['type']=="Common"){
                $itemsc[]=$finfo['item'];
                $itemsidc[]=$finfo['id'];
            }           

        elseif($finfo['type']=="Other"){
            $itemso[]=$finfo['item'];
            $itemsido[]=$finfo['id'];

            }
    }

}    else{echo "ERROR !<br>";}
//print_r($itemsm);
?>

<div class="scrolltop"><h4>Go to Top</h4></div>
<div class="clothesform">
        <form action="place-order" method="post" name="orderform" id="orderform">

        <div><label for="phone">Phone </label> 
                <?php include('jqueryserverphone.php');?>
                        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>      
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
                <h3>Order Details</h3>  
                        <div class="male">      
                            <h4>Male</h4>
                            <div class="colhead1">Item</div><div class="colhead2">Qty</div><div class="colhead3">Cost</div><div style="clear:both"></div>
                            <?php 
                            $result=$orderdb->query("SELECT * FROM rates ORDER BY item");

                            for($i=0;$i<count($itemsm);$i++)
                            {
                                $itemname= strtolower(preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/',"",$itemsm[$i]));
                                $itemname=str_replace(array("_"," ","/"),"",$itemname);
                                $itemlabel=ucfirst($itemsm[$i]);
                                $itemlabelname=$itemname."lbl";
                                ?>      

                            <div>
                                <label for="<?php echo $itemname;?>"><?php echo $itemlabel;?><input type="hidden" name='<?php echo $itemlabelname;?>' value="<?php echo $itemlabel;?>"> </label> 
                                <input type="number" data-validation="number" name ="<?php echo $itemname;?>" class="clothesqty" id="<?php echo $itemname;?>"
                                 <?php if(isset($_POST[$itemname])){echo  " value='$_POST[$itemname]'";}else{echo " value='0'";}?>>
                                <div id="<?php echo $itemname."cost";?>" class="ittot">
                                    <?php
                                        include('testfunct.php');
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                            </div>
                            <?php   } ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="female">
                                <h4>Female</h4>
                                <div class="colhead1">Item</div><div class="colhead2">Qty</div><div class="colhead3">Cost</div><div style="clear:both"></div>
                                <?php
                                for($i=0;$i<count($itemsf);$i++)
                                {       
                                $itemtitle=$itemsf[$i];
                                $itemname= strtolower(str_replace("_","",preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/',"",$itemsf[$i])));
                                $itemname=str_replace(array("_"," ","/"),"",$itemname);
                                $itemlabel=ucfirst($itemsf[$i]);
                                $itemlabelname=$itemname."lbl";

                                ?>

                                <div>
                                    <label for="<?php echo $itemname;?>"><?php echo $itemlabel;?> <input type="hidden" name='<?php echo $itemlabelname;?>' value="<?php echo $itemlabel;?>"> </label> 
                                    <input type="number" data-validation="number" name ="<?php echo $itemname;?>" class="clothesqty" id="<?php echo $itemname;?>"
                                     <?php if(isset($_POST[$itemname])){echo  " value='$_POST[$itemname]'";}else{echo " value='0'";}?>>
                                    <div id="<?php echo $itemname."cost";?>" class="ittot">
                                        <?php
                                        include('testfunct.php');
                                    ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="clear:both"></div>
                                </div>

                                <?php   } ?>

                        </div>

                        <div class="common">
                                <h4>Common Apparel</h4>
                                <div class="colhead1">Item</div><div class="colhead2">Qty</div><div class="colhead3">Cost</div><div style="clear:both"></div>
                                <?php
                                if(!empty($itemsc)){
                                for($i=0;$i<count($itemsc);$i++)
                                {       
                                $itemtitle=$itemsc[$i];
                                $itemname= strtolower(str_replace("_","",preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/',"",$itemsc[$i])));
                                $itemname=str_replace(array("_"," ","/"),"",$itemname);
                                $itemlabel=ucfirst($itemsc[$i]);
                                $itemlabelname=$itemname."lbl";

                                ?>

                                <div>
                                    <label for="<?php echo $itemname;?>"><?php echo $itemlabel;?> <input type="hidden" name='<?php echo $itemlabelname;?>' value="<?php echo $itemlabel;?>"> </label> 
                                    <input type="number" data-validation="number" name ="<?php echo $itemname;?>" class="clothesqty" id="<?php echo $itemname;?>"
                                     <?php if(isset($_POST[$itemname])){echo  " value='$_POST[$itemname]'";}else{echo " value='0'";}?>>
                                    <div id="<?php echo $itemname."cost";?>" class="ittot">
                                    <?php
                                        include('testfunct.php');
                                    ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="clear:both"></div>
                                </div>

                                <?php   } 
                                }?>

                        </div>


                        <div class="others">
                                <h4>Household and Others</h4>
                                <div class="colhead1">Item</div><div class="colhead2">Qty</div><div class="colhead3">Cost</div><div style="clear:both"></div>
                                <?php
                                for($i=0;$i<count($itemso);$i++)
                                {
                                $itemtitle=$itemso[$i];
                                $itemname=strtolower(preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/',"",$itemso[$i]));
                                $itemname=str_replace(array("_"," ","/"),"",$itemname);
                                $itemlabel=ucfirst($itemso[$i]);
                                $itemlabelname=$itemname."lbl";

                                ?>

                                <div>
                                    <label for="<?php echo $itemname;?>"><?php echo $itemlabel;?> <input type="hidden" name='<?php echo $itemlabelname;?>' value="<?php echo $itemlabel;?>"> </label>
                                    <input type="number" data-validation="number" name ="<?php echo $itemname;?>" class="clothesqty" id="<?php echo $itemname;?>"
                                    <?php if(isset($_POST[$itemname])){echo  "value='$_POST[$itemname]'";}else{echo "value='0'";}?>>
                                    <div id="<?php echo $itemname."cost";?>" class="ittot">
                                    <?php
                                        include('testfunct.php');
                                    ?>

                                    </div>
                                    <div style="clear:both"></div>
                                </div>

                                <?php   }   ?>
                                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="clear:both"></div>
                        <div id="totalcost"><?php 
                            if(isset($_POST)){
                                totitem($_POST);
                                //echo $p;  
                                //totcost();
                            }else{echo "0";}
                        ?></div>
                        <div style="clear:both"></div>          
                    <div class="submit"><input Type="submit" name="clothessub" value="Place Order"></div>   
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> var item= <?php echo json_encode($arraytable); ?>;</script>
```

The testfunct.php file is where I am calling the total function as mentioned earlier.

the json_encode variable has nothing to do with this part of the problem. It is only to pass the variable to my external js file for a different purpose.

**Edit**

The actual form is  [here](http://www.mylaundrywala.com) . Where I have reset the form values on edit to zero since the total items value is creating above mentioned problem otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go to the confirmation step, you have a form (`<form action="register" method="post">`) with hidden input fields, which hold the entered values. Then, when you go back to edit your Order, this form disappears, but only visually - the code is there in the source and the hidden input fields are there, with all the values. Then when calculateSum() is called upon keyUp, the sum is calculated for ALL input fields, including the hidden ones which add up.

One solution is to change the selector from "input" to "input[type=number]":
Your code:

```
$("input").each(function() {
    //add only if the value is number
    if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0 && this.value.length<=3) {
        sum += eval(parseInt(this.value));
    }
});
```

Change it to:

```
$("input[type=number]").each(function() {
    //add only if the value is number
    if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0 && this.value.length<=3) {
        sum += eval(parseInt(this.value));
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually I dont get the same sum. It adds on to the previous total in a compounding fashion each time the form is called without refreshing the page

Comment: Can you give us the HTML code structure for the form and the related elements, used in the jQuery code. Thanks.

Comment: Also in this line of code: `sum += eval(parseInt(this.value));` what is the purpose of eval(), I think you don't need it and `sum += parseInt(this.value);` would be just enough

Comment: I have edited and added the order for code to the question. Also have removed the eval function from the original code. Still same result.

Comment: I saw the code you provided but unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe. Upon submitting the form, do you write the data into the database?

Comment: Actually first it goes to a page asking the user to proceed to next page where it is submitted to a database. At the confirmation page, I have given an edit button that will call the order form via javascript again. I want this page to have the previously filled data so that it becomes for the user to edit his choices. And when he changes the values in the input, the totals also have to change accordingly. You can check this here http://www.mylaundrywala.com . As of now, I am resetting form values to zero on edit call since the total items is giving the above problem otherwise.

Comment: OK, now that I visited the site, I saw what the problem is. 
When you go to the confirmation step, you have a form (<form action="register"...>) with hidden input fields, which hold the entered values. Then when you go back to edit your Order, this form disapears, but only visually - the code is there in the source and the hidden input fields are there, with all the values. Then when calculateSum() is called upon keyUp, the sum is calculated for ALL input fields, including the hidden ones which add up. Change the jQuery selector in the calculateSum() function to skip the hidden fields.

Comment: You have hit the nail on the head, @cvetan Mihaylov ! You are a saviour ! This is right !! God bless you and thanks a ton for your consistent efforts to get this solved ! You are the best trouble shooter in the world !! :)